# Уникальные значения в списке Python

Tags: python, list, случайные-числа

Задача: случайным образом получить 5 чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 75, занести их в список, проверить чтобы среди этих 5 чисел не было совпадений и результат вывести на экран.

Мой код:

```
my_list = []

for i in range(5):
    numbers = random.randrange(1, 75)
    my_list.append(numbers)

    my_list.sort()
    i += 1

print(my_list)
```

Как сделать проверку, чтобы программа удаляла совпадения и заменяла их уникальными значениями?

Comment: а какие действия в случае удачной/неудачной проверки?

Comment: Строчка i+= 1 не нужна. Конструкция for i in range() инкрементирует автоматически.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Встроенными средствами генерируем список нужного диапазона, перемешиваем его, и берем любой кусок длиной 5

```
import random

rn = [x for x in range(1,76)]
random.shuffle(rn)
print(rn[:5])
```

Того же самого можно добиться вручную с использованием алгоритма [тасования Фишера-Йетса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

Для малой выборки подход с множествами пригоден, но по мере увеличения выборки проверка очередного элемента может занимать всё большее количество времени (главное - непредсказуемое)

Comment: Вся соль в том, чтобы написать алгоритм проверки значений на совпадения и если они есть - удалить их и заменить на уникальные. Т.е. если выпало, например: 1,7,18,18,43 - программа должна убрать повтор и заменить его на уникальное значение! При использовании множества вид будет такой: 1,7,18,43 - числа 4, а нужно 5!

Comment: Это прописано в задании? Какова точная формулировка задачи?

Comment: Ну это же очевидно - я просто разжевал детали. Задача: случайным образом получить 5 чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 75, занести их в список, проверить чтобы среди этих 5 чисел не было совпадений и результат вывести на экран. Просто выводить сообщение на экран о совпадении я умею) Надо именно удалять совпадения, чтобы значения были уникальными!

Comment: Нет, это не очевидно. Если о проверках явно не сказано в задаче, то Вы, вероятно, можете увязть в XY problem (в данном случае - пытаетесь преодолеть трудности, возникшие из-за собственной интерпретации, а не идёте к получению результата оптимальным путём).  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/ Однако я не видел точной формулировки и могу быть неправ.

Comment: Вопрос в задаче дополнен. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @AlexGraph, вы просите *"Как сделать проверку, чтобы программа удаляла совпадения и заменяла их уникальными значениями?"* Вам дали программу, которая сразу, гарантированно даёт результат без совпадений и дополнительных проверок. Почему Вам это не подходит?

Comment: Это где Вы увидели такую программу?

Comment: @AlexGraph в этом ответе

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что AlexGra не совсем понимает, что ему нужно на самом деле. Решение, предложенное @MBo очень простое и элегантное. Однако, сдаётся мне, что мое решение - намного более эффективное. Предположим, что надо сгенерировать ту же самую пятёрку, только числа в диапазоне не до 75, а до 75000000... Мой алгоритм затратит то же самое время, а вот алгоритм MBo - в 1000000 раз больше.

Comment: @Sergey Всё верно, нужно выбирать компромисс в зависимости от условий. Ваше решение полностью удовлетворяет условиям автора, тем более что он отфильтровывать нацелен.

Comment: MBo благодарю. Ваш вариант подошёл отлично, просто я на самой ранней стадии изучения языка и не сразу понял что делает этот код, что Вы предложили)

Comment: @AlexGraph Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)

Comment: Отметил. Благодарю))

Answer (score 2):

Несколько проще и понятней:

```
import random

my_list = []
count = 0

while count<50:
    numbers = random.randrange(1, 75)

    if numbers not in my_list: 
        my_list.append(numbers)
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Значение {0} уже встречалось".format(numbers))

my_list.sort()

print(my_list)
```

Длину списка увеличил до 50, с тем, что бы наверняка возникли повторения. Если длину списка задать более 75, то программа не завершится никогда, т.к. невозможно выбрать более 75 **разных** случайных чисел.

Comment: Да, я так тоже пробовал, не то. И выводить сообщение на экран о повторениях не нужно) Программа автоматически должна генерировать уникальные числа и выводить на экран только их. Ничего лишнего!

Comment: @AlexGraph Ничего не понял из Вашего комментария. Попробую по пунктам:.

Comment: 1) "*выводить сообщение на экран о повторениях не нужно*"  - я это написал только для того, что ДОКАЗАТЬ Вам, что повторяющиеся значения действительно отбраковываются. В чём проблема - убрать оператор *print()* ?!

Comment: 2)  *Программа автоматически должна генерировать уникальные числа* - Программа ничего не **генерирует**. Генерирует функция *random*, А программа только **отбирает** уникальные. Мой пример ведёт себя как-то по другому?

Comment: 3) *выводить на экран только их*  - Оператор *print(my_list)* печатает что-то лишнее ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randrange


my_list = [randrange(1, 76)]
while (len(my_list) != 5):
    num = randrange(1, 76)
    my_list.append(num)
    if (my_list.count(num) > 1):
        my_list.pop()

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Благодарю за отзыв. Вопрос уже решили выше)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вас не устраивает вариант с перемешиванием, то предлагаю использовать конструктор множеств который и удалит дубликаты:

```
# граница рандомизатора
start = 1
end = 76
# необходимая длина списка случайных элементов
elcount = 5

# сгенерим список из 5 элементов
randlist = list()
for _ in range(5):
    randlist.append(random.randint(start, end))

# будем генерить пока число уникальных не будет нужным
while len(set(randlist)) < elcount:
    randlist = list(set(randlist))
    randlist.append(random.randint(start, end))

print(randlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно и так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

print(set(random.randrange(1, 76) for a in range(5)))
```

В питоне есть списки - list().
А есть множества - set().
Во множество помещается только уникальные значения.

Ответ не в кассу :(
В вашем случае нужно рекурсивно проверять массив пока не будет повторений.